# getRegistrationId returns null some times

Tags: android

my application logic require that I check if this is a new handset or already registered handset before. Hence, I use :

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

However, I notice some time is return null, but when I retry it works fine. it seems like **getRegistrationId** takes sometime:

- Is my conclusion correct.
- if so how do you advice to proceed, shell I for example display progress bar so that user could wait until getRegistrationId returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCM will take time to procees.

And It is possible that Server may be down or anything related to connectivity problem between GCM or server or device happened.

So It is better to call GCM registrar from Login activity as well as Launcher activity because in case Our device did't get register in starting phase due to any reason like mention above then It has a chance to registering the device again.